# Maxing Out Perks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The level cap in The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim is 50 but you can keep going after that to about level 70 if I understand it correctly. This means you can get about 70 of the 250 perks in the game.

Jail time can lower your kills so that you can train them up again would that allow you in theory to get all 250 perks by getting to level 250?

Let me know what you think?

Comment: Try it out and let us know. Get jailed until a skill lowers, then raise it and see if XP goes up/level up.

Comment: I will do it tonight and report back...

Comment: As bwarner below pointed out (and I saw on a 'loading screen' message), jail time simply removed the current levels experience for a skill, it no longer has the ability to lower the skill. So no, beyond command line cheating, you cannot do this anymore it seems.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think jail time lowers your skills.  It just eliminates your progress counter towards the next skill point.  So no, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: yup jail time doesn't lower skills anymore

Answer (score 10):

It's an organic cap - a mathematical cap.  There is no overall level limit, but each skill caps at level 100.  Since your overall level is based on the number of skill advancements you have, and since the number of skill advancements required to gain a level advancement increases as your level increases, it is mathematically impossible to go beyond level 80.

In other words, once you max all your skills, you will be level 80 and there will be no way to level any further.

80 is therefore maximum number of perks as well, since you only receive perk points upon leveling.

Comment: The level cap is [actually 81](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37818/1980) (which *does* still translate to 80 perks, as you get no perk at level 1).

Answer (score 3):

With **[Patch 1.9](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch#Version_1.9)**, individual skills can be made "**Legendary**", denoting them with an Imperial symbol. This will reset the skill to 15, and perks used for that skill may be redistributed. Gaining levels in that skill will affect leveling again, thus **effectively removing the level cap of 81**. There is no restriction on the number of times that skills can be made Legendary. *This change makes it theoretically possible to obtain every single perk in the game*.

<sup>Source: [UESP wiki, "Skyrim - Leveling" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveling)</sup>

Comment: I was gonna say this if it hadn't already been said.