# Can you raise your character's main ("Hard Cap" - Level 81) level higher in Dawnguard?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I didn't flesh out my level and perk strategy as well as I would have liked (I got it nailed down at level 65). I also assumed the Hard Cap was level 100. My character will still come out, I'd say, approx. 85% the way I would've  liked. I'm at level 72 now (gotta get a life, huh :D), and I've mapped out my remaining perks.

Anyhoo, if there are new skills, that will allow me to level up further and pick new perks, which would be awesome. Oh, fyi, I don't like spoilers and I don't want to learn the Dawnguard story (I'm like that with most games), thus my ignorance of Dawnguard.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is no. You cannot raise your level cap beyond the current hard cap which is reached when you max out all base skills to 100.

While Dawnguard introduces 2 new skill trees, Vampire and Werewolf building these trees is self contained and does not contribute to your overall level. You gain perks within these trees through in game actions/achievements, not 'xp'.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct because the game was changed -- see @galacticninja's answer above.

Answer (score 6):

With **[Patch 1.9](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch#Version_1.9)**, individual skills can be made "**Legendary**", denoting them with an Imperial symbol. This will reset the skill to 15, and perks used for that skill may be redistributed. Gaining levels in that skill will affect leveling again, thus **effectively removing the level cap of 81**. There is no restriction on the number of times that skills can be made Legendary. *This change makes it theoretically possible to obtain every single perk in the game*.

<sup>Source: [UESP wiki, "Skyrim - Leveling" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveling)

(Shamelessly copied from [my other answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/115321/4797).)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You may only raise the main player level beyond 81 by using the console on PC version. You are using the PS3, thus you are unable to level beyond the main player level of 81.