# Is it possible to maximize all the skills and gain all the perks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In one playthrough, will it be possible for me to get every single perk and max all my skills?

Comment: +1 Because I know several people (including myself) who came to this post immediately after buying Skyrim. Very useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the 1.9 skyrim patch there is no limit to the levels you can achieve, so you could get all the perks in theory.

Alternatively, on pc, there are mods that can give you extra perk points. For example I use [Spend Dragon Souls For Perks](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=13544). Otherwise search the workshop for 'perk' and see what you find: e.g. [Perk Potions](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=23736)

Comment: note that getting all the skill perks will require you to max out your skills and make them legendary, which resets them back to lvl 15 and lets you raise them again; some of them will need to be reset more than once, so it will be a *tedious* process

Comment: Any recommended mods that can give extra perk points?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Or you find one skill that is easy to level up, and just keep resetting that.

Comment: It costs 251 perk points to fully max out the perk tree.  To pull this off without mods you need to reset a skill 147 times in order to reach level 252.

Answer (score 30):

It is possible to raise all skills to 100.

It is not possible to acquire all possible perks by reaching level 100 in every skill, since the number of perks vastly outnumbers the perks earned by leveling to that state ([80](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37818/336)).

**There is no soft cap** - the 80th perk is just as (relatively) easy to earn as the 1st.

However, as of the 1.9 release, you can "reset" a skill from 100 back down to 0, which means you can reach arbitrarily high levels, and finally max out your perks.

Comment: I've seen it said that 50 is the soft cap and 70 is the hard cap.

Comment: Indeed. Hence, "or so" :)

Comment: Holy crap! Only 70? I really need to plan my perks out now. I've been kinda going willy-nilly with only a little bit of care.

Comment: @Arkive what do you mean by soft and hard caps?

Comment: I'd love a hard answer on max number of perks

Comment: @MorganTiley - 80. [The max level is 81.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37818/336)

Comment: @TrewTzu It means that lvl 50+ (the softcap) is when getting to the next level gets increasingly difficult (more so than from lvl 1-50) and the lvl 80/81 harcap is when you can't lvl any further.

Comment: @Holger That's incorrect. There is no softcap.

Comment: @RavenDreamer yeah I saw that in another question... thought Todd Howard has said in several interviews that most people would get to lvl 50

Comment: That's because by Lv. 50 you have most of the skills you're interested in maxed or very close to max, so most people wouldn't bother going further. To reach 81, you have to raise _every single skill_ to 100.

Comment: Does resetting skills to earn all the perks work on the Xbox 360 version as well? That is, is patch 1.9 available on consoles too?