# What's the max level we can get in Skyrim and max perks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to maximize all the skills and gain all the perks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35217/is-it-possible-to-maximize-all-the-skills-and-gain-all-the-perks)

I was wondering if it was possible to max out all skills, perks or there's a max level so you'll have to choose wisely ?

Comment: See also: [What's the level cap in Skyrim?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34076/whats-the-level-cap-in-skyrim)

Comment: Since the question have over 10k views... could be great to be reopened and protected no ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "hard cap" is level 81, while the "softcap" is level 50.

This means from level 50 onward it gets progressively harder to level until level 81 (when all skills reach 100) you can't level at all.

[Source](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2011-04-20-tesv-skyrim-level-cap-explained)

Comment: This answer is no longer correct; once you get a skill to 100 you can mark it as 'legendary' and have it reset to 15 and refund all perks.